# Change variable for all further observations

Tags: r

I am trying to create a type of a "switch" in my data where when a specific event happens, a binary indicator will switch from 1 to 0 for all the next observations (data sorted by time). Below is a sample of my data currently.

```
Time Event ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4 ID_5
1    0     1    1    1    1    1
2    0     1    1    1    1    1
3    0     1    1    1    1    1
4    0     1    1    1    1    1
5    ID_2  1    1    1    1    1
6    0     1    1    1    1    1
7    ID_3  1    1    1    1    1
8    0     1    1    1    1    1
```

And then this is what I want:

```
Time Event ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4 ID_5
1    0     1    1    1    1    1
2    0     1    1    1    1    1
3    0     1    1    1    1    1
4    0     1    1    1    1    1
5    ID_2  1    0    1    1    1
6    0     1    0    1    1    1
7    ID_3  1    0    0    1    1
8    0     1    0    0    1    1
```

As you can see, when "EVENT" takes a value other than 0, I want the variable that matches what is in the EVENT value to switch from 1 to 0, and I want it to stay 0 as the observations continue to go on. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry missed that. What is shown is my desired output. I'll edit to show what it currently is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this by using `library(data.table)`, creating a 'lookup' table of when the events occur, and then using a `non-equi` join to update the values that are after the event

```
## extract just the rows where the updates occur
eventRows <- df[df$Event != "0", c("Time", "Event")]

library(data.table)

## set as data.tables
setDT(eventRows)
setDT(df)

## melt into long-form
df_melted <- melt(df, id.vars = c("Time", "Event"))

## perform a non-equi join, and update-by-reference the values
## meeting the criteria
df_melted[
  eventRows
  , on = .(variable == Event, Time >= Time)
  , value := 0
]

## put back into wide form
df_res <- dcast(df_melted, formula = Time + Event ~ variable)
df_res
#    Time Event ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4 ID_5
# 1:    1     0    1    1    1    1    1
# 2:    2     0    1    1    1    1    1
# 3:    3     0    1    1    1    1    1
# 4:    4     0    1    1    1    1    1
# 5:    5  ID_2    1    0    1    1    1
# 6:    6     0    1    0    1    1    1
# 7:    7  ID_3    1    0    0    1    1
# 8:    8     0    1    0    0    1    1

## convert back to a data.frame using
## setDF(df)
```

---

#### Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "Time Event ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4 ID_5
1    0     1    1    1    1    1
                 2    0     1    1    1    1    1
                 3    0     1    1    1    1    1
                 4    0     1    1    1    1    1
                 5    ID_2  1    1    1    1    1
                 6    0     1    1    1    1    1
                 7    ID_3  1    1    1    1    1
                 8    0     1    1    1    1    1", header = T)
```

Answer (score 3):

Run a `cumsum` counter to see where each variable is detected, and then overwrite the corresponding variables:

```
dat[3:7] <- lapply(names(dat[3:7]), function(x) 1-cumsum(dat$Event==x) )
dat

#  Time Event ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4 ID_5
#1    1     0    1    1    1    1    1
#2    2     0    1    1    1    1    1
#3    3     0    1    1    1    1    1
#4    4     0    1    1    1    1    1
#5    5  ID_2    1    0    1    1    1
#6    6     0    1    0    1    1    1
#7    7  ID_3    1    0    0    1    1
#8    8     0    1    0    0    1    1
```

This method won't be reliant on the columns actually existing beforehand either.

```
vars <- paste("ID",1:5,sep="_")
dat[vars] <- lapply(vars, function(x) 1-cumsum(dat$Event==x) )
```

Comment: With `cummin`, you can do `lapply(names(dat[3:7]), function(x) cummin(dat$Event != x))` or `cumprod`: `lapply(names(dat[3:7]), function(x) cumprod(dat$Event != x))`.